# Can't get button to move on li:hover when .active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, hover

I'm a little new to javascript and used a small one to get my menu to appear en move the button accordingly but I wanted to implement submenu's. Now when I want the button to move when the submenu is activated(hovered on main li) it won't.

What am I doing wrong?

A little side note, the menu also expands (on hover 2nd li) when it's not activated that's my second question.

http://jsfiddle.net/drjvdyhb/

```
    body {
    font: 400 18px'Fjord One', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1em;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #c0c5ce;
}
header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2c353a;
}
header ul.nav {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
}
header ul.nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    list-style: none;
}
header ul.nav li a {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    font: 400 1.15em'Fjord One', serif;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #848e92;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
header ul.nav li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222b2f;
}
header ul.nav li:hover ul li a {
    color: #848e92;
    background-color: #2c353a;
}
header ul.nav li ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222b2f;
}
header ul li ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
header ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
header ul.nav li ul li {
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
}
header ul.nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
header ul.nav li:hover button.toggle-nav {
    top 90px;
}
header ul li ul li a {
    font: 400 1em'Fjord One', serif;
    color: #848e92;
}
header.active ul.nav li a {
    height: 60px;
    opacity: 1;
    line-height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
header.active ul.nav li ul li a {
    Height: 30px;
    line-height: 100%;
}
button.toggle-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
    width: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #38a6a6;
    font: 400 1.2em'Allan', serif;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
button.toggle-nav:hover {
    height: 50px;
}
button.toggle-nav span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
header.active button.toggle-nav {
    top: 60px;
    background-color: #256f6f;
}

            /* My try so far */

header.active ul.nav li.hvr a:hover button.toggle-nav {
    top: 90px;
}                                                 
header.active button.toggle-nav span {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#nav-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content:'';
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
    top: 10px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
    bottom: 10px;
}
#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
    top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set** `position: relative` for `button.toggle-nav` and **remove** `top: 30px;`,

Have a look at this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x7d9eeLc)

Answer (score 0):

```
try this css code
#nav-toggle {
    z-index: 10000000;
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
    top: 0px;
}
```